# write a constexpr constructor which constructs an array of another class with default constructor deleted

Tags: c++, constexpr

I have two classes A and B, where B contains an array of A.
I will get a compiler error of this constructor of B (complains that the default constructor of A cannot be referenced), unless the default constructor of A is not deleted. What I understand about this compiling issue is that, by writing this constructor of B, due to the lack of initialization list, compiler will assume to add a default constructor of A into it, which will cause an error since it's deleted.
How can I get rid of this error?

```
constexpr int data[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
constexpr size_t N = sizeof(data)/sizeof(int);

struct A { 
    A() = delete; // error in B constructor if using this
    // constexpr A() = default; // no error if using this instead
    constexpr A(int a): a_(a) {}
private:
    int a_ = 0;
};

struct B{
    constexpr B() { // error: the default constructor of A cannot be referenced
        for(size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) arr_[i] = A(data[i]);
    }
private:
    A arr_[N];
};
```

Comment: *complains that the default constructor of A cannot be referenced* It doesn't complain, it shows a very fine error message, that you have forgot to post.

Comment: Question is: Do you intend to keep the default constructor deleted and still want a solution?

Comment: well, actually I have already pasted the error into the code directly

Comment: yes, I want to keep the default one deleted, if possible

Comment: What is the topic of chapter of your C++ textbook that this practice problem is from? There are several potential approaches to do this; need to know which specific advanced C++ technique you're supposed to learn.

Comment: Which C++ standard? constexpr changes a lot between standards. Also, can you use std::array instead of C array?

Comment: any approach is ok for me, just want to keep the default A constructor deleted

Comment: Come on y'all, what "debugging details" does this one need? We don't close questions for being basic (if this is even "basic" in the first place).

Comment: I don't agree with the closing reason either and I was about to post an answer, but you'll get it [here](https://godbolt.org/z/TMr8nxEWd) instead.

Comment: I am using -std=c++17

Comment: @u0804138 C++17 is not a big problem. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/3eej8Een1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The direct solution when `N` is `5` is to just initialize `arr_` in the member initializer list:

```cpp
struct B {
    constexpr B()
        : arr_{A(data[0]), A(data[1]), A(data[2]), A(data[3]), A(data[4])} {}

private:
    A arr_[N];
};
```

This becomes cumbersome if you need to change `N` or make it into a template parameter. You can generalize the initialization by using `std::array` and a lambda:

C++20 and later:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <utility>

struct B {
    constexpr B()
        : arr_{[]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
              return std::array{A(data[I])...};
          }(std::make_index_sequence<N>())} {}

private:
    std::array<A, N> arr_;
};
```

---

In C++14 / C++17, you can't use lambda templates so you can move that out to a helper function:

```cpp
struct B {
private:
    template<std::size_t... I>
    static constexpr std::array<A, N> helper(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        return std::array<A, N>{A(data[I])...};
    }
public:
    constexpr B()
        : arr_{helper(std::make_index_sequence<N>())} {}

private:
    std::array<A, N> arr_;
};
```

Comment: Nice!  Just what I would've said for C++17.  I need to learn C++20.